# Reduce Beeline Hive CSV verbosity

Tags: hive, beeline

I am new to using beeline and I am using a statement like the following:

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://myserver' --outputformat=csv2 -f export.sql > results.csv
```

The statement works as desired but the resulting CSV is very verbose with all the INFO statements preceding and following the actual CSV data. How can I modify the statement so that the only items in the CSV is the actual data and none of the other statements? I just want a clean dataset in `results.csv`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that by making `silent=true` and `verbose=false`

```
beeline -u 'jdbc:hive2://myserver' --outputformat=csv2 --silent=true --verbose=false -f export.sql > results.csv
```